# Proof verification for a theorem about a harmonic function on the unit disc

Tags: complex-geometry, harmonic-functions

**On why this is here** I tried posting on [math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4483846/proof-verification-for-a-theorem-about-a-harmonic-function-on-the-unit-disc) but I got no comments or answers. I even bountied the question but I am still not getting any responses. I am getting the sense that I wasn't posting in the correct forum. If this is also not the correct place to ask this please let me know.

I would like to prove the following result

[image]

I will be quoting the previous result and its proof :

[image]

**Proof for Theorem 1.4** Suppose $\exists (a,b)\in D(0,1)$ such that $u(a,b)>0$. Let
\begin{align*}
X = \left\{z: |z|\leq 1 \quad \text{and} \quad z\neq z_0  \right\}
\end{align*}
If $u$ has a maximum in $D(0,1)$, then apply the same argument as in the proof of the above theorem. Else consider $C_{R}$ defined by
\begin{align*}
C_{R}=\left(D(0,1) \cup \partial D(0,1)\right) \setminus D(z_0,R)
\end{align*}
illustrated as

[image]

By construction $u$ achieves its minimum and maximum on the boundary $\partial C_{R}$. Let
\begin{align*}
M= \sup \left\{\max_{C_{R}}u  \mid 0<R<1 \right\}
\end{align*}
which exists as $u$ is bounded and because the set is non empty. By assumption $u$ can not achieve $M$ on  $X$.

Now given $\epsilon>0$, define
\begin{align*}
T=\left\{\max_{C_{R}}u \mid  0<R<\epsilon \right\}
\end{align*}
By construction
\begin{align*}
M=\sup T.
\end{align*}
By definition, given $\delta >0$, there exists $\tau $ with  $0<\tau<\epsilon$ such that
\begin{align*}
\max_{C_{\tau }}u &  > \sup T + \delta  \\ 
 &  = M +\delta 
\end{align*}
by applying the definition of supremum of $T$.
Now we use continuity. For any point $z_1 $ on the boundary of the open disc, except for $z_0$, we have that given $A>0$ , there exists $B>0$ such that
\begin{align*}
|z-z_1 |<B \implies  |u(z)-u(z_1 )|<A
\end{align*}
By hypothesis, the maximum on $C_{\tau }$ lies on the semi circle. Let $z_2$ be that point. Then let $z_3$ be one of the points where the circle and semi circle intersect. Then
\begin{align*}
|z_3-z_2|<2\tau
\end{align*}
geometrically as they lie on the same circle of radius $\tau $. Take $A<M$. Now set $\epsilon<\frac{B}{2}$, so $\tau<\frac{B}{2}$. Then
\begin{align*}
|z_3 -z_2|<B 
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
|u(z_3)-u(z_2)|&  = |u(z_2)| \\ 
 &  > M +\delta  > A
\end{align*}
which contradicts the continuity.

**Question:** Does my proof hold?

Comment: At the beginning. Did you set $z_0=(a,b)$? The argument from the above Theorem does not apply directly, since precisely $u\neq0$ on the boundary, and isn't continuous. Where are the points of discontinuity in your discussion?

Comment: Hi @username , apologies for the unclarity. I set $z_0$ to be the point of discontinuity on the unit disc. I set $(a,b)$ to be a point in the closed unit disc, with $z_0$ removed, such that $u(a,b)>0$. Is this clearer? Also, I are you sure that a similar argument to the above theorem doesn't hold? I am not saying it applies directly, but an identical proof works.

Comment: The "but u=0 on the boundary" part doesn't hold.

Comment: Hi, what I am using from the first theorem is not the statement. I am using the proof. More specifically, I am using the fact that we proved that the maximum is always achieved on the boundary. Does that make moresense?

Answer (score 1):

This is a consequence of the Phragmen-Lindelof Principle, whose general formulation is the following: Let $D$ be a bounded region
in the plane, and $\zeta_0\in\partial D$. Let $u$ be a subharmonic function in $D$ bounded from above, and assume that
$$\limsup_{z\to\zeta} u(z)\leq 0$$
for all $\zeta\in\partial D\backslash\{\zeta_0\}$. Then $u\leq 0$ in $D$.

Proof. WLOG assume that $D$ is contained in the unit disk, and $\zeta_0=0$. Then the function $$u_\epsilon(z)=u(z)+\epsilon\log|z|$$ with any $\epsilon>0$
satisfies
$$\limsup_{z\to\zeta} u_\epsilon(z)\leq 0\quad \zeta\in\partial D,$$
so $v_\epsilon\leq 0$ by Maximum Principle. Now for any fixed $z$,
let $\epsilon\to 0$, and we conclude that $u(z)\leq 0$.

This has an evident generalization to finitely many boundary points instead of one, and to unbounded regions. Also the condition of boundedness from above can be relaxed in many ways.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I have two questions. 1) Shouldn't you remove the point of dscountinuity from $\partial D$ for the first statement of the proof? 2) Do you think that my proof holds? (you might have to also refer to the comments)